How can I pass a namedtuple attribute to a method without using a string?
I'm trying to create a class to represent a list of named tuples and I'm having trouble with accessing elements by name. Here's an example:
from typing import NamedTuple


class Record(NamedTuple):
    id: int
    name: str
    age: int


class NamedTupleList:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def attempt_access(self, row, column):
        print(f'{self._data[row].age=}')
        r = self._data[row]
        print(f'{type(column)=}')
        print(f'{column=}')
        print(f'{r[column]=}')

data = [Record(1, 'Bob', 30),
        Record(2, 'Carol', 25),
        Record(3, 'Ted', 29),
        Record(4, 'Alice', 28),
        ]
class_data = NamedTupleList(data)

print('show data')
print(f'{data[0]=}')
print(f'{type(data[0])=}')
print(f'{data[0].age=}')

print('\nshow class_data')
print(f'{type(class_data)=}')

print('\nattempt_access by index')
class_data.attempt_access(0, 2)

print('\nattempt_access by name')
class_data.attempt_access(0, Record.age)  # why can't I do this?

Produces:
data[0]=Record(id=1, name='Bob', age=30)
type(data[0])=<class '__main__.Record'>
data[0].age=30

show class_data
type(class_data)=<class '__main__.NamedTupleList'>

attempt_access by index
self._data[row].age=30
type(column)=<class 'int'>
column=2
r[column]=30

attempt_access by name
self._data[row].age=30
type(column)=<class '_collections._tuplegetter'>
column=_tuplegetter(2, 'Alias for field number 2')

    print(f'{r[column]=}')
             ~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not _collections._tuplegetter

So I can successfully access 'rows' and  'columns' by index, but if I want to access a column (i.e. namedtuple attribute) through a method call I get an error. What's interesting is that the column value is _tuplegetter(2, 'Alias for field number 2') so the index is known in my method but I can't get to it. Does anyone know how I can access this value so that I can pass a name to the method? I'm trying to avoid passing the name as a string - I'd really like to take advantage of the namespace since that's one of the advantages of a namedtuple after all.

Interesting question. The field is a descriptor, so you can invoke it:
class NamedTupleList:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def attempt_access(self, row, column):
        r = self._data[row]
        try:
            val = r[column]
        except TypeError:
            val = column.__get__(r)
        return val

Demo:
>>> class_data.attempt_access(0, 2)
30
>>> class_data.attempt_access(0, Record.age)
30


That's really useful. There' a section on this in Python in a Nutshell (pp. 119-120) but I think I'll need to read it about 10 times to understand it.

3.3.2.2. Implementing Descriptors and 3.3.2.3. Invoking Descriptors may also be useful references. This is the same protocol by which attribute access works on namedtuple instances normally, i.e. r.age is roughly equivalent to Record.age.__get__(r),  the only difference being that we pass in the "instance" r explicitly.

So for type hinting, I guess I could do this? def attempt_access(self, row: int, column: int|Callable) -> Any:

@MikeP Yeah, nah- we don't call the descriptor, and it is not actually callable anyway. Type-hinting a descriptor is probably worthy of a new question, rather than expounding in the comments.

OK - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78451100/what-is-the-type-hint-for-a-descriptor
