What is the type hint for a descriptor?
This is a new question related to How can I pass a namedtuple attribute to a method without using a string? .
How would I type hint the column parameter in method attempt_access. It can be either an int or the attribute of a namedtuple.

from typing import NamedTuple


class Record(NamedTuple):
    id: int
    name: str
    age: int


class NamedTupleList:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def attempt_access(self, row: int, column) -> any:
        r = self._data[row]
        try:
            val = r[column]
        except TypeError:
            val = column.__get__(r)
        return val

data = [Record(1, 'Bob', 30),
        Record(2, 'Carol', 25),
        Record(3, 'Ted', 29),
        Record(4, 'Alice', 28),
        ]
class_data = NamedTupleList(data)

print('attempt_access by index')
v = class_data.attempt_access(0, 2)
print(v)

print('attempt_access by name')
v = class_data.attempt_access(0, Record.age)
print(v)


the type of this is collections._tuplegetter (you could have just checked type(Record.age)), but there is no connection to your Record type.  And you probably shouldn't use it because it is an implementation detail anyway

The appropriate type hint would be in the form of a subclass of typing.Protocol (indicating which of __get__ et al. are defined and required).

@juanpa.arrivillaga IIUC you can't use it for type-checking purposes, the type-checker will not recognize it as a valid attribute of the collections module.

@chepner sorry this is a little beyond me, even after reading the documentation. What would that look like in my example?

See the example in typing.Protocol.

There's a really straightforward way of doing this that comes fully typed (I suspect this was added since the first question):
from typing import NamedTuple

class Record(NamedTuple):
    id: int
    name: str
    age: int

data = [
    Record(1, 'Bob', 30),
    Record(2, 'Carol', 25),
    Record(3, 'Ted', 29),
    Record(4, 'Alice', 28),
]

print('attempt_access by index')
v = data[0][2]
print(v)

print('attempt_access by name')
v = data[0].age
print(v)

A list of NamedTuple already has a pretty nifty interface that's fully typed and very close to what you're looking for. Hope this is useful!
